# field-value-query returning unexpected results when used with 'unfiltered' search in MarkLogic

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8, cts-search

I am getting false results with `field-value-query` when used with `'unfiltered'` search.

I will explain the problem with sample data as given below.

XML:

```
<book>
    <name>Dixit</name>
    <age>25</age>
    <entry>
        <isbn>
            <type>hbk</type>
            <value>1234567</value>
        </isbn>
        <isbn>
            <type>pbk</type>
            <value>111111</value>
        </isbn>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <isbn>
            <type>hbk</type>
            <value>1234567</value>
        </isbn>
        <isbn>
            <type>pbk</type>
            <value>222222</value>
        </isbn>
    </entry>
</book>
```

Above xml can have multiple `<entry>` elements. But two or more `<entry>` can't have same `<type>`.

I want all the entries having the combination of one or more `isbn` type, values.

As in the above example. I want `<entry>` having both `hbk:1234567 AND pbk:111111`

To achieve this I am running the below `cts:query`

```
cts:search(
  fn:doc()/book//entry,
  cts:and-query((
    cts:field-value-query("hbk", "1234567", ("case-insensitive")),
    cts:field-value-query("pbk", "222222", ("case-insensitive"))
  )),
  "unfiltered"
)
```

Output:

```
<entry>
    <isbn>
        <type>hbk</type>
        <value>1234567</value>
    </isbn>
    <isbn>
        <type>pbk</type>
        <value>111111</value>
    </isbn>
</entry>
```

According to me the the above output is wrong as it should return below `<entry>`.

```
<entry>
    <isbn>
        <type>hbk</type>
        <value>1234567</value>
    </isbn>
    <isbn>
        <type>pbk</type>
        <value>222222</value>
    </isbn>
</entry>
```

Even if I am running cts query with only one `field-value-query` as given below, getting the same result (entry having **pbk** value as **111111**)

```
cts:search(
  fn:doc()/book//entry,
    cts:field-value-query("pbk", "222222", ("case-insensitive")),
  "unfiltered"
)
```

**Fields I have created:**

`pbk : /book/entry/isbn[./type = 'pbk']/value`

`hbk : /book/entry/isbn[./type = 'hbk']/value`

**Index settings: (Same for both fields)**

[image]

**Note: For filtered search it is working fine.**

Please help me to understand why this unexpected behaviour and what I can do to correct it.

**Tried:**

```
cts:search(
  fn:doc()/book//entry,
  cts:element-query(
    fn:QName('','isbn'),
    cts:and-query((
      cts:field-value-query("hbk", "1234567", ("case-insensitive")),
      cts:field-value-query("pbk", "222222", ("case-insensitive"))
    ))
  ),
  "unfiltered"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your cts:and-query with a cts:element-query() on your isbn element. The below is an approximation of what I mean:

```
cts:search(
  fn:doc()/book//entry,
  cts:element-query(xs:QName("isbn"), 
      cts:and-query((
        cts:element-value-query(xs:QName("hbk"), "1234567", ("case-insensitive")),
        cts:element-value-query(xs:QName("pbk"), "222222", ("case-insensitive"))
      ))
   ),
  "unfiltered"
)
```

Comment: `xs:QName("hbk")` and `xs:QName("pbk")` are not elements. Both are values for `<type>` element.

Comment: I understand that,. But I analysed your sample content and gave a solution that I think works based on the data structure you provided. I see no need for the fields if you use element-value-queries and scope the query with an element query.

Comment: Okay.. I tried wrapping the cts:and-query with a cts:element-query() on isbn element still getting the same results.
I have updated the question and added the cts query I have tried. Please have a look.

Comment: To use an unfiltered cts:element-query() to check co-occurrence of child element values within the parent, it's also necessary to index value positions. You can turn on the index setting in the Admin UI. That said, David's suggestion to change the model to minimize repeated elements is often the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

Unfiltered returns the first element in the fragments that match. To get the result you want, you need to use filtered results or re-model your data or use fragment roots. Reverse the order of your elements and you will see - its always the first element in the searchable expression that is returned. That is the nature of fragments and filtered vs unfiltered.

Comment: Thanks David for this valuable info.
I can not use `filtered` search as it will be very slow in my case.
Can not re-model the data, changing will take a lot of time.
Yes, definitely I will try with `fragment root`, But I also would like to know, How we can achieve this(getting `entry` having the particular combination of multiple `type` AND `value`) without using `fragment root` and `re-modeling` the data.